# In Python, how do I check if a string has only alphabets without the built in functions(.islower etc)?

Tags: python

This is my code. it seems to be checking only the first character. I'd like to know how to fix it.

```
import string

ASCII_LOWERCASE = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
ASCII_UPPERCASE = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
DECIMAL_DIGITS = "0123456789"
ALPHABETS = ASCII_LOWERCASE + ASCII_UPPERCASE

def is_alpha(string):
    for c in "string":
        if c in ALPHABETS:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Comment: (1.) If you have screwy requirements ("I can't use built-in functions") they need to be very well-defined, and you need to explain why you can't do things normally. (2.) If you're going to import `string`, you may as well use `string.ascii_lowercase` and `string.ascii_uppercase` instead of using your own constants and introducing the possibility of typoes.

Comment: (3.) You're **returning** from inside your `for` loop. That ends your function. Your for loop is in your function, so that's over too. That's why it's "only checking the first character."

Comment: this is a school assignment and all the variables are preset ,I'm limited to these variables and when I say I can't use built in functions I mean string manipulators present in python,also a condition in the assignment. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: OK. It's too late now but in the future you need to put all of that specifically in your question up front. Too many of these questions get dozens of comments and 3 or 4 "bad" answers while requirements like those are teased out.

Comment: ```return all(c in ALPHABETS for c in string)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not return in every iteration, only return False when you find something that is not in ALPHABET.  What about this?

```
def is_alpha(your_string):
    for c in your_string:
        if c not in ALPHABETS:
             return False
    return True
```

Comment: I would add a `return True` at the end of the `for` loop. It seems unusual for such a function to return `None` if the string is entirely alphabetical.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, actually you are right. I was busy adding some explanation. Thanks , fixed

Answer (score 1):

There's several issues with your code here.
In your function definition you say

```
for c in "string"
```

which means you're checking the characters in the string literal "string".
You'll need to remove the quotes to have it refer to your parameter and actually check the string you're looking at.  Further, you should change the name of your parameter and variable to something less ambiguous than string.

As Two-Bit Alchemist points out, you're returning from inside the loop so if the first character is in ALPHABETS then it returns and doesn't execute any more.

Which goes to the final issue.  You're returning False if it is an alpha character instead of true.  If you change

```
if c in ALPHABETS:
    return False
```

to

```
if c not in ALPHABETS:
    return False
```

then delete the else branch and put the return True after the loop it will work as you intend.

Comment: You've completely missed the answer to the OP's actual problem, which is that the function is "only checking the first character", which is because (as I already pointed out above) there is a `return` statement inside the loop.

Comment: He also has his return values backwards.

Answer (score 1):

actually its almost half right:

```
def is_alpha(string):
    for c in string:
        if not c in ALPHABETS:
            return False

    return True
```

short circuiting on False is ok but you need to finish the loop to determine True

Comment: oops several answers at the same time - i didnt see the others

Answer (score 0):

Change your function like this:

```
def is_alpha(string):
    for c in string:
        if c not in ALPHABETS:
            return False
    return True
```

First of all, you had `for c in "string":` in your code. There you are creating a new string ("string") and looping through the characters in it. Instead, you want to loop through the parameter passed to your function. So remove the double quotes.
Your function returns after first character because you are returning in both cases. Return true only when all characters are in `ALPHABETS`